# Same margin-left auto, same IE11, both W7, different layout

Tags: css, margin, internet-explorer-11

I have 2 pc's, both windows7. Both using IE11 (same build).
To display a table in the center of the screen i use this div tag:

```
#centerblock
    {
    display: block;
    background-color: #F8F8F8; 
    border: 1px solid #000088; 
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    }
```

On one pc the block is in the center, on the other one the block is totally left aligned. In de used style attributes (F12) there is no difference.

On the failing-to-center pc, chrome has no problem with centering.

Is there an IE setting that prevents this div to work?
Or has anyone this seen before (en found the solution)?

TIA
Hans

Comment: Open the console, check what `Document Mode` is used on both browsers.

Comment: different browsers have different ways to display css formatting. Chrome and IE will have some differences. And why not just do margin: 0 auto; instead of left and right set to auto?

Comment: 'Both using IE11 (same build)... On one pc the block is in the center, on the other one the block is totally left aligned.' It's not about differences between IE and Chrome - it's the same browser (or at least the same major version).

Comment: Thanx both for the fast responses. raina77ow's hint to check the console gave me more info. The failing pc gave a warning about 'Document Mode 5'.

Comment: (Sorry, I entered to soon). Some research brought me the answer. The failing pc was in 'compatibility view' mode. Removing that  (in IE) results in a centered block. Also I'm gonna figur out how to deal with this in de code. (the in other questions mentioned head meta-data). Thanx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading through your comment, you had mentioned one browser being in compatibility mode...use this meta tag which will force the brwser to open in a specific mode...in this case the latest IE environment available.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

hope this helps.